# Android: Adding Layouts to HorizontalScrollView

Tags: java, android, layout, horizontalscrollview

I'm trying to create something similar to the home screen layout. This consists of multiple vertically oriented LinearLayouts within a single horizontally oriented LinearLayout, all housed in a HorizontalScrollView. I've written it as a custom class called 'HomeLayout' extending HorizontalScrollView.

[image: hierarchyviewer]

```
LinearLayout wrapper = new LinearLayout(getContext());
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
wrapper.setLayoutParams(params);
wrapper.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

addView(wrapper);

for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout) View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.screens, null);    
    linear.setLayoutParams(params);

    wrapper.addView(linear);
}
```

The problem is 'screen2' has width '0' when added.

This only works if I call this in onDraw() and use getMeasuredWidth() and getMeasuredHeight() instead of LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT. And even then, I'm not sure if that's the right thing to do.

Furthermore I'm unable to reference the views 'wrapper', 'screen1', 'screen2' in onCreate().

I loosely followed this link: http://blog.velir.com/index.php/2010/11/17/android-snapping-horizontal-scroll/

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hoping this helps others. I solved my problem by implementing onMeasure() in the following way:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);

    for(int i = 0; i < mWrapper.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = mWrapper.getChildAt(i);
        child.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, 
        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    }

    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```